# Adding radial gradient to multiple separated arcs with same center point

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, gradient, radial-gradients

I need to add multiple arcs to one svg elements (every one got different animation). I need to fill them with radial gradients, but now, the center of radial gradient is not in the centre of whole svg element, but in the centre of specific arc. How it looks now. First i make all of the gradients i need in defs.

```
var tmpgrad=null;

    for( var k = 0; k<data.length;k++){
        tmpgrad = grads
            .append("radialGradient")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("r", "50%")
            .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "grad" + k; });

        tmpgrad
            .append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .style("stop-color", data[k].endColor)
            .style("stop-opasity", 0);
        tmpgrad
            .append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .style("stop-color",data[k].startColor)
            .style("stop-opasity", 1);
    }
```

Then I make my arcs with deferent options:

```
    var width= 1200;
    var height=360;

    var oArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(iRadius)
        .outerRadius(oRadius);

    var oPie = d3.layout.pie()
        .startAngle( sA )
        .endAngle( eA )
        .sort(null);

    var group = svgDrawer.append("g");


    var oPath = group.selectAll("g")
        .data(oPie([0,200]))
        .enter()
        .append("path");

    oPath
        .attr("fill",function(d, i){ if(i==1){ i=0; } else { i = id; } return "url(#grad" + i +")"; })
        .attr("d",oArc)
        .each(function(d){
            this._current = d;
        });
```

But in the result as i said before i got the separated arcs with gradient starting in the middle of every arc element (path actually). How can i solve that.

I am the beginner in svg and javascript subject.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057) link could be of help? In this example, to create a gradient he breaks up a path into many smaller pieces and applies a different color to each one, giving the same effect as a gradient fill. Not sure if this is what your question is asking though, could you provide a picture?

Comment: In this example he is using one dataset for whole picture. In my example I got different dataset for each part of the circle. I am animating arcs in different directions, and that makes it impossible to treat it as a one dataset.